# i want to get path of selected image from gridview in android ? i'm using recycler for this gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

i'm developing an app in which selected images can be upload to server at a time...for that i need to get a path of all selected images in an array and then have to pass this array to the upload activity...so that all images can get uploaded to server one by one automatically....

here is my adapter class

package com.akshay.nmiua;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide ;
import com.technotalkative.multiphotoselect.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mImagesList;
    private Context mContext;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
        mContext = context;
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mImagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.mImagesList = imageList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<mImagesList.size();i++) {
            if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(mImagesList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return mTempArry;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String imageUrl = mImagesList.get(position);

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load("file://"+imageUrl)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImagesList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }
    }

}
```

here is my itemoffset class..

```
package com.akshay.nmiua;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.annotation.DimenRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;


public class ItemOffsetDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int mItemOffset;

    public ItemOffsetDecoration(int itemOffset) {
        mItemOffset = itemOffset;
    }

    public ItemOffsetDecoration(@NonNull Context context, @DimenRes int itemOffsetId) {
        this(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(itemOffsetId));
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                               RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.set(mItemOffset, mItemOffset, mItemOffset, mItemOffset);
    }
}
```

here is my main activity..

```
package com.akshay.nmiua;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.technotalkative.multiphotoselect.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;


public class MultiPhotoSelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private static final int REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 123;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_multi_photo_select);
        populateImagesFromGallery();
    }

    public void btnChoosePhotosClick(View v){

        ArrayList<String> selectedItems = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();

        if (selectedItems!= null && selectedItems.size() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.this, "Total photos selected: " + selectedItems.size(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Selected Items: " + selectedItems.toString());
        }
    }

    private void populateImagesFromGallery() {
        if (!mayRequestGalleryImages()) {
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<String> imageUrls = loadPhotosFromNativeGallery();
        initializeRecyclerView(imageUrls);
    }

    private boolean mayRequestGalleryImages() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }

        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }

        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            showPermissionRationaleSnackBar();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        }

        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE_PERMISSION: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        populateImagesFromGallery();
                    } else {
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            showPermissionRationaleSnackBar();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> loadPhotosFromNativeGallery() {
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy + " DESC");

        ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            imageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

            System.out.println("=====> Array path => "+imageUrls.get(i));
        }

        return imageUrls;
    }

    private void initializeRecyclerView(ArrayList<String> imageUrls) {
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageUrls);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),4);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemOffsetDecoration(this, R.dimen.item_offset));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }

    private void showPermissionRationaleSnackBar() {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.button1), getString(R.string.permission_rationale),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.this,
                        new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
            }
        }).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is the problem? You only described what you want. And you also did not describe how you implemented all. You are not even explaining how the user would select images.